# How do I select elements from json_encode d array?

Tags: arrays, object, json

I'm using JSON and javascript to retrieve data from a php file which connects to the database. This is how my php code looks like:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
$data[] = $row;
}

header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo json_encode($data,true);
```

This is my Javascript:

```
var displayfeeds = new ajaxObject('ajax/users/display.feeds.php');
displayfeeds.callback = function (responseText,status) {
    var feed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseText));
    $("#feeds-feedback").html(feed);
}
displayfeeds.update();
```

When I run this, it prints out an array like this:

```
[
    {
        "userID":"39160902151",
        "content":"bar bar bar bar",
        "published":"2011-06-07 10:33:35"
    },
    {
        "userID":"5896858666",
        "content":"foo foo foo foo foo",
        "published":"2011-06-06 22:54:51"
    }
]
```

My question is: **How do I then display say "userID" and "content" from this?**
I have really struggled. I am new in JSON.

Comment: There's no need to double encode your JSON, get rid of the `JSON.stringify()` call.  `JSON.strigify()` is the JavaScript equivalent to the PHP command `json_encode()`.  Since you received it as a string there is no need to do it in your JS. `JSON.parse()` takes a JSON string and converts it into an object, PHP has an equivalent function called `json_decode()` which you would use if you passed a JSON string back to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your json objects into html to display them.  So in your callback function I would do something like this:

```
displayfeeds.callback = function (responseText,status) {
    var feed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseText));
    var html = '';

    // build html for each feed item
    for (var i = 0; i < feed.length; i++) {

        html += '<h3>UserID:: '+ feed[i]['userID'] +'</h3>';
        html += '<p>'+ feed[i]['content'] +'</p>';
        html += '<div><strong>published</strong>: '+ feed[i]['userID'] +'</div>';
        html += '<hr />';
    }
    // append content once all html is built
    $("#feeds-feedback").append(html);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I just had to remove stringify and follow both of your guys' suggestions. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

To get first user id:

```
var feed = JSON.parse(responseText);
feed[0].userID
```

Comment: You should see a grey checkmark below the score on each answer. Click on that to select that answer.